# отобразить 10 персонажей swapi.co

Tags: javascript

Не получается подтянуть 10 персонажей,   получается одного либо всех, помогите плеас

```
function getDetail(apiURL) {
    axios.get(apiURL).then(function(response) {
        showDetail(response.data);
    });
}

function showDetail(data) {

    for (i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {



        properties = properties + data.results[i].name + "\n" + data.results[i].birth_year + "\n"  + data.results[i].gender + "\n"  + data.results[i].skin_color + "\n" + data.results[i].mass + "\n" ;


        // name1.innerText = name1.innerText + "\n" + data.results[i].name;
    }
    if (data.next) {
        getDetail(data.next);
    } else {
        console.log(properties); // name1.innerText = names;
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = properties;

    }
}
var properties = "";


getDetail("https://swapi.co/api/people");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var n = 0;

function showDetail(data) {
  var len = Math.max(Math.min(data.results.length, 10) - n, 0)

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    properties = properties + data.results[i].name + "\n" + data.results[i].birth_year + "\n"  + data.results[i].gender + "\n"  + data.results[i].skin_color + "\n" + data.results[i].mass + "\n" ;
  }

  n += len;

  if (data.next && n < 10) {
    getDetail(data.next);
  } else {
    console.log(properties);
    document.getElementById('demo').textContent = properties;
  }
}
```